# JDBC - Multiple queries in NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, jdbc

Is there any way I can execute more than 1 query using a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` in *one single* call?

Comment: are you referring to retrieving multiple resultsets?

Comment: no, i want to run 2 queries like this: `query1 ; query2`, one after the other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer: You can't. JDBC statements should execute only one query / statement at a time.

The longer answer: You usually can't, because either the driver or the database server doesn't support it, and formally the JDBC specification doesn't allow for it (if you read a bit between the lines in both the specification and the Javadoc). However, some driver (ie MySQL Connector/J) do allow you to execute multiple queries in one go (though you might need to specify a connection property to enable it, not sure).